# SwiftUI SecureField seems to resize slightly when first character is entered

Tags: swiftui

I have a SecureField and I have it styled, the thing is when I type the first character the SecureField slightly changes it's not really significant but you can see a tiny jump in the UI and the minor change is kind of offputting. I was wondering if anyone has encountered this before and maybe has an idea for a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue when the `SecureField` is embedded in a `Form`. The height appears to shrink by about 1.5 pixel when the prompt is replaced by the first character placeholder. If the field is not inside a form then it doesn't seem to be a problem.

My guess is that the font that a Form uses for the placeholder characters is smaller than the font used for the prompt, so the field re-sizes when the content changes.

There are a couple of simple workarounds:

1. Set a minimum height on the field. I found that a minimum height of 21 seems to work without causing it to grow larger. If you use a `@ScaledMetric` property wrapper then this will adapt automatically to changes in the text size:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) private var secureFieldHeight: CGFloat = 21
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .frame(width: 200)
                .frame(minHeight: secureFieldHeight)
                .overlay {
                    Rectangle().stroke()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Set the font explicitly. I found that setting `.body` as font didn't fix the problem, but some other standard font sizes do work, as does this:

```swift
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) private var secureFieldFontSize = CGFloat(17)
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .frame(width: 200)
                .font(.system(size: secureFieldFontSize))
                .overlay {
                    Rectangle().stroke()
                }
        }
    }
```